# How to change publishing rate of a node to a topic?

Tags: ros, rate, frequency, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,here are the publishing rate on the following topics:--

```
/odom--->Caverage rate: 5.002   min: 0.193s max: 0.210s std dev: 0.00788s window: 39
/scan--->Caverage rate: 4.997   min: 0.193s max: 0.210s std dev: 0.00782s window: 39
/tf----->Caverage rate: 40.086  min: 0.000s max: 0.112s std dev: 0.04128s window: 250
```

**How can i increase the publishing rate on /odom and /scan topics?**

I have a P3AT robot in spawned in the simulated environment (USARSim).

////////////////////////////////////////////////Question Update 1///////////////////////////////////////

hi @gvdhoorn, i have an amcl node which subscribingis to `/tf` from rossim at a higher rate and also publishing the `/tf`, to others node, i am in a problem because both nodes rossim and amcl are doing both things publishing and subscribing together, now my concern is that i suppose i remapped it like `<remap from="tf" to="tf_throttle"/>` then it could also change publishing topic along with its subscribing topic, please take a look on this [rqt_graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypu5mormrjj8bvd/rqt_auto_rviz_goal.png?dl=0)  which is creating problem and confusion.

My rossim Node is publishing to `/tf` at the rate of 40hz, i want to rossim to publish at the rate of 5hz, i used `throttle` but it publishing at another topic `/tf_throttle` at the reduced rate, now if i remap the amcl to subscribe to `/tf_throttle` and because publishing to the `/tf` also then it might also change it publishing topic and other node like rviz and move_base won't be able to get `/tf` data from amcl. please take a look at my [rqt_graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypu5mormrjj8bvd/rqt_auto_rviz_goal.png?dl=0)

Thanks a lot

**////////////////////////////////////////////////Question Update 2///////////////////////////////////////**

hi @gvdhoorn,

1. Here is the scenario, suppose i have a node `n` and two topics `t1 and t2`, n is a default publisher of `t1` and also subscribes to this topic 't1'.
2. Now i want that node `n` should subscribe to the topic `t2` instead of topic `t1`, but at the same time i also don't want `n` to change its publishing topic and it should retain its default publishing topic.

How can i do it because i suspect that **remapping** can change both topics *(publishing and subscribing)* for the node `n`?? please suggest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199592/how-to-change-publishing-rate-of-a-node-to-a-topic?/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-16**:
Whatever sends this topics (probably some usarsim driver node) must adjust that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only the source of those messages can increase the publishing rate.

If the author of the node that publishes the `/odom` and `/scan` transforms has provided a configuration interface through which you can configure the publication rate, use that.

If there is no such configuration option, you'll have to change the source of the node(s) in question.

---

Edit: note that *decreasing* message rate is possible without changing the publisher. This is known as *throttling*, and can be done using the [topic_tools/throttle](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle) node.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-16**:
@gvdhoorn converted this to answer as it gives instructions on how to proceed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-16**:
Ok. I'll update it a bit then.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-17**:
hi @gvdhoorn, i have gone through your solution, throttle and drop is doing good but they are publishing on another topic at modified publishing rate, but i want to publish on the same topic, is there any trick so that i can do so.

Thanks for looking into it. :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-18**:
You want to look at [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap). It works for subscribers as well.

Note btw that `topic_tools` nodes cannot *increase* the publication rate of their input.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-19**:
hi @gvdhoorn, i have update my question and described it more please take a look on that..

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-19**:
hi @gvdhoorn, please [take a look on this too](http://answers.ros.org/question/199631/warning-costmap2dros-transform-timeout-and-could-not-get-robot-pose-cancelling-reconfiguration-keeps-on-coming/), here is what i am doing because of that i am getting this publishing rate problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-22**:
If I understand you correctly, you could probably have `amcl` publish on `/tf_amcl` (using remapping), then (again using remapping) have the `throttle` node subscribe to `/tf_amcl` and publish on `/tf`.

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-12-23**:
hi @gvdhoorn, i am really very sorry for inconvenience, i have updated my question again and make it more precise, please take a look on that.

Thank you.